# Deployment process - ASP.NET, SQL Server to shared hosting

Tags: asp.net, hosting, deployment

After a number of failed deployment attempts (configs overwritten, files missing, out dated etc) to our shared hosting server I thought I might get some insight on processes to make deployment run more smoothly.

We use SQL Compare to move database related stuff over and that seems to work well. 
The web site itself is in SVN source control, to deploy we create a tag for the current release and then export the files. We then upload the exported files to the server through ftp manually making sure we are not overriding server specific files.

Is there any (free) tools that can assist in this or do you have a solid process that you generally follow?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359869/how-does-your-company-deploy-its-software/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the web stuff, I'd recommend  you look at the asp.net [web deployment project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) add-on for Visual Studio. Using the web deployment project, you can take advantage of various degrees of pre-compilation and handle all that messy config file search-replace stuff too. Doesn't work with Web Dev Express though...

For the database end, SQL Compare is a good way to go, so if that is working fine for you stick with it.

Comment: This looks like the sort of thing I am after, I will check it out.

Comment: If you have access to it, the database tools in Visual Studio 2008 Database Professional Edition (and the full Team Suite version) are REALLY good for deployment scenarios. My only complaint is that it doesn't automate deploying seed data for new databases. If you go that route for the DB end, do make sure you upgrade to the "GDR R2" version (sorta like a service pack for the DB tools stuff).

It is a good tool, though a tad expensive if you don't already own it.